# How to deliver multiple .csv files to SFTP server using pysftp "put" method in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sftp, paramiko, pysftp

I need to put multiple file on SFTP server. But I am confused here of how to loop through them if path to SFTP requires file name and extension? Which in my case it will be dynamic.

```
# sftp path where file should be delivered
sftp_path = fr'/Incoming/{filename_PRE}.csv' # if not supply filename it will give permission error. Why?

##  push file to sftp server
def push_file_sftp():
    try:
        ## HostKey 
        keydata = b"""AAAABBB2222888555="""
        key = paramiko.RSAKey(data=decodebytes(keydata))
        cnopts = sftp.CnOpts()
        cnopts.hostkeys.add('hostname', 'ssh-rsa', key)
        ## Credentials 
        s = sftp.Connection(host='hostname', username='username', password='psswd',cnopts=cnopts)
       # how can I put 2 files here?
        s.put(filepath_PRE, sftp_path)
        s.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
push_file_sftp()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just use update the remote path with the correct filename:

```
sftp_path = '/Incoming'

filepath_PRE = "file1"
s.put(filepath_PRE, sftp_path + "/" + filepath_PRE + ".csv")
filepath_PRE = "file2"
s.put(filepath_PRE, sftp_path + "/" + filepath_PRE + ".csv")
```